# the direct shape element inside the family. How to do it?

Tags: revit

How can I create or post DirectShape element into family? I have read RevitApi. There are few methods for creating shape - extrusion, blend ... and other.
I am finding way creating family with geometry from DirectShape element or from other element example DWG file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DirectShape.CreateElement` method: http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/bee8a24f-704e-44d9-e187-9e031548a6d2.htm

Comment: Yes. I know this method.  But i will get direct shape that is not defined. I need create family with geometry as  DIrectShape when i imported DWG file

Comment: DWG file import is managed differently. I do not believe that DWG can be imported directly into direct shape. Can you achieve that in the user interface? If not, then it is probably not possible programmatically either. If you wish to create a direct shape from a DWG file, you can read and analyse the DWG file contents yourself using the AutoCAD.NET, RealDWG or Forge Design Automation API, understand the geometry, and create the corresponding direct shape yourself using the Revit API.

Comment: I can import DWG and create few DirectShape shapes by API. But i need to create family and move geometry from created DirectShape to new Family